# UWP/Visual Studio 2019: Where can I see the computed value and value source of a component's property?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019, uwp-xaml

When I select a component, all I can see in Visual Studio 2019 is the property values immediately set on those components (e.g. "No brush" for the `Page.Background` property, depicted in the screenshot below). Yet, I cannot see the property values inherited from a style being applied nor the key of such style.

Where can I find the [lightweight styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles#lightweight-styling) style key being utilized by a property, so I can use that information to navigate to or alter the corresponding theme style?

Plus: If such information exists, is there an option to jump to the corresponding `ThemeDictionaries` entry in a `ResourceDictionary` file (or a meta file if the theme style is provided by Windows Runtime)?

[image: Visual Studio UWP project]

Comment: If you have add the custom ResourceDictionary into application resource, when you **build**  your project, you will find the the value in the VS properties window.

Comment: And if you want to use this resource key, you need add them like this  `Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"`.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't think that manually referencing a `ThemeDictionary` is supposed to be *lightweight* styling. Please refer to [this GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2790#issuecomment-726424882) issue where I'm discussing this.

Comment: Have you edited your app'theme to light theme?